# Xamarin Slider Control - Line not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, slider

Relatively new to Xamarin.

I have a Slider control on a page in my app.  In Android (only O/S I have tested so far).  But I just see the thumbnail.  I do not see the horizontal line.  This means it is not obvious to the User that it is a Slider!

I have found this https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/pull/2085  It seems to indicate it is a bug on later versions of Android, but there is a workaround.

Quote: "the only thing we need to do is to add a android:layerType="software" attribute to our layout file"

I am unsure how to do that.  What layout file?  Where do I create the "layout file".  Can somebody help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web, I created a customer Slider Renderer

```
public class CustomSliderRenderer : SliderRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate a CustomSliderRenderer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context to use</param>
    public CustomSliderRenderer(Context context)
        : base(context) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the Slider changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The details of the change</param>
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (!(e.OldElement is null) || e.NewElement is null)
            return;

        // The line colour to the left of the image
        Control.ProgressTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.Black.ToAndroid());
        Control.ProgressTintMode = PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn;

        // The line colour to the right of the image
        Control.ProgressBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.Black.ToAndroid());
        Control.ProgressBackgroundTintMode = PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the Slider is layed out.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="changed">True if the layout has changed, else false</param>
    /// <param name="left">The left of the Slider</param>
    /// <param name="top">The top of the Slider</param>
    /// <param name="right">The right of the Slider</param>
    /// <param name="bottom">The bottom of the Slider</param>
    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean && !(Control is null))
        {
            var thumb = Control.Thumb;

            int thumbTop = Control.Height / 2 - thumb.IntrinsicHeight / 2;

            thumb.SetBounds(thumb.Bounds.Left, thumbTop, thumb.Bounds.Left + thumb.IntrinsicWidth, thumbTop + thumb.IntrinsicHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML

```
           <Slider 
                Grid.Row="7"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                x:Name="DaysAbandonedVisible"
                Value="{Binding DaysAbandonedVisible}"
                Maximum="60"
                Minimum="0"
                ThumbImageSource="Slider.png"/>
```

Slider.png is just a black circle, larger than the little default pink one.  This has the effect of showing the line (black to the left, 'light' black to the right).  These colours are in the Control.ProgressTintList and Control.ProgressBackgroundTintList respectively.